# Multiplying inside a bracket with indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you multiply a variable from outside a bracket inside that has indices applied on it?

eg. can $a(b+c)^{d}$ become $(ab+ac)^d$?

Thanks

Comment: I would call $d$ an *exponent* in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for a counterexample just consider $3 \cdot 2^3 \ne (3\cdot 2)^3$.